# mongorestore results in truncated collection

Tags: mongodb

On server (source) running 3.0.15 run:

- mongodump --db fuel-*****-**** --out /home/
- the output is then gzipped,tar'd and scp to local mac
- collection count on server 70198

On Mac (dest) running 3.6.2

- mongorestore -d fgtest fuel-*****-****
- collection count is 1000

What am I doing wrong?

- file sizes all verified between source/dest
- the other two collections match (both very small, doc count ~ 40 in each)

Comment: try restoration with verbose option to see what prints on each document

Comment: @Saravana - verbose shows all is well for the collections, just fails to create an index on a collection (which is exact replica and is OK)

Comment: Found the issue.  As above, It failed to create the index for another collection (which was expected) but this stopped the full restore of the larger collection.  Using --noIndexRestore allowed a full restore